# How to convert a polygon to a multipolygon object?

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, shapefile, r-sf

I'm trying to cast a shapefile as a multipolygon using either of the following arguments from `st_read()` function:

- `promote_to_multi=TRUE` and\or
- `type=0`

But no matter what, the geometry type is set as *Polygon*.

Is there another way to convert a sf object from polygon to multypolygon in R?

Comment: Welcome. Can you please share a reproducible example of your data. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- st_cast(x, "MULTIPOLYGON")
```